# RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object

Tags: android, web-service

Não consigo entender e muito menos fazer rodar minha app..
Alguem consegue me dar uma luz?

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try{
                    Intent i = new Intent(Activity_Questionario.this, Activity_Conf_Inicio_Ques.class);


                    PerguntaAdapter adapter = (PerguntaAdapter) lv.getAdapter();
                    List < Pergunta > ListaPergunta = adapter.getPerguntas();

                    final ArrayList < SerializablePair< Integer, Boolean > > respostas = new ArrayList < SerializablePair< Integer, Boolean > > (ListaPergunta.size());

                    for (Pergunta pergunta: ListaPergunta) {
                        respostas.add(new SerializablePair< Integer, Boolean >(pergunta.getId(), pergunta.getResposta()));
                    }

                    Log.i("Verificação", "Verificando: " + respostas);
                    //Log.i("Senha no Click", "Senha: " + senha);

                    i.putExtra("respostas", respostas);

                    startActivity(i);

                }catch(Exception erro){
                    erro.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

E a outra classe que recebe os valores...
Acredito que o erro esta dando nessa linha do ArrayList

```
try{
            ArrayList<SerializablePair<Integer, Boolean>> respostas = (ArrayList<SerializablePair<Integer, Boolean>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("respostas");
            Log.i("Respostas na Confirmação", "Respostas: "+respostas);

            String urlPost = "http://"+l.IP+"/projetotcc/android/respostas.php";
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametrosPost = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            for(SerializablePair<Integer, Boolean> item : respostas){

                Log.i("Entrou", "Entrou no for(SerializablePair<Integer, Boolean> item : a)");
                parametrosPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("codigoQuestionario", item.first.toString()));
                parametrosPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("codigoPaciente", item.second.toString()));

            }

        }catch(Exception erro){
            erro.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Erro: "+erro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

LogCat:

> 10-17 14:12:39.090: W/System.err(2785): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object (name
>   = br.com.projetotcc.utilitarios.SerializablePair) 10-17 14:12:39.100: W/System.err(2785):     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2144) 10-17
>   14:12:39.100: W/System.err(2785):     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2016) 10-17 14:12:39.110:
>   W/System.err(2785):   at
>   android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2235) 10-17
>   14:12:39.110: W/System.err(2785):     at
>   android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1655) 10-17 14:12:39.120:
>   W/System.err(2785):   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1986)
>   10-17 14:12:39.130: W/System.err(2785):   at
>   android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226) 10-17
>   14:12:39.130: W/System.err(2785):     at
>   android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223) 10-17 14:12:39.150:
>   W/System.err(2785):   at
>   android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:1254) 10-17
>   14:12:39.150: W/System.err(2785):     at
>   android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.java:4182) 10-17
>   14:12:39.150: W/System.err(2785):     at
>   br.com.projetotcc.visao.Activity_Conf_Inicio_Ques.onCreate(Activity_Conf_Inicio_Ques.java:45)
>   10-17 14:12:39.162: W/System.err(2785):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 10-17
>   14:12:39.162: W/System.err(2785):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   10-17 14:12:39.180: W/System.err(2785):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
>   10-17 14:12:39.180: W/System.err(2785):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   10-17 14:12:39.180: W/System.err(2785):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 10-17
>   14:12:39.190: W/System.err(2785):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   10-17 14:12:39.200: W/System.err(2785):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-17
>   14:12:39.200: W/System.err(2785):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-17 14:12:39.210:
>   W/System.err(2785):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 10-17
>   14:12:39.220: W/System.err(2785):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-17
>   14:12:39.240: W/System.err(2785):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-17 14:12:39.240:
>   W/System.err(2785):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   10-17 14:12:39.251: W/System.err(2785):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 10-17
>   14:12:39.260: W/System.err(2785):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-17 14:12:39.280:
>   W/System.err(2785): Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException:
>   android.util.Pair; IllegalAccessException 10-17 14:12:39.300:
>   W/System.err(2785):   at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.resolveConstructorClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:694)
>   10-17 14:12:39.310: W/System.err(2785):   at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:655)
>   10-17 14:12:39.310: W/System.err(2785):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1816)
>   10-17 14:12:39.310: W/System.err(2785):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
>   10-17 14:12:39.329: W/System.err(2785):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
>   10-17 14:12:39.329: W/System.err(2785):   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
>   10-17 14:12:39.341: W/System.err(2785):   at
>   android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2142) 10-17
>   14:12:39.350: W/System.err(2785):     ... 23 more

Classe SerializablePair

import java.io.Serializable;
import android.util.Pair;

public class SerializablePair extends Pair implements Serializable {

```
public SerializablePair(F first, S second) {
    super(first, second);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>**Nota:** Em Android, geralmente, é mais prático iniciar a análise da `stack trace` a partir do fim indo avaliando os problemas até encontrarmos a  última referencia a "Caused By". Essa última referência geralmente aponta para o problema específico que estamos a enfrentar.</sup>

Não tens todo o output do LogCat, mas a causa do teu problema parece ser:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: android.util.Pair; IllegalAccessException
```

Em suma, estás a tentar aceder a um campo ou método não acessível no decorrer de uma serialização ou deserialização.

---

Decompondo um pouco o problema:

## [IllegalAccessException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/IllegalAccessException.html)

> Thrown when a program attempts to access a field or method which is not accessible from the location where the reference is made.

Que traduzido:

> Lançada quando um programa tenta acessar um campo ou método que não é acessível a partir do local onde é feita a referência.

## [android.util.Pair](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html)

> Container to ease passing around a tuple of two objects. This object provides a sensible implementation of equals(), returning true if equals() is true on each of the contained objects.

Que traduzido:

> Contentor para facilitar a passagem em torno de uma tupla de dois objetos. Este objeto fornece uma implementação sensata de equals(), retornando true se equals() é verdadeiro em cada um dos objetos contidos.

## [java.io.InvalidClassException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InvalidClassException.html)

> Signals a problem during the serialization or or deserialization of an object.

Que traduzido:

> Sinaliza um problema durante a serialização ou deserialização de um objeto.

Comment: Então @Zuul, Eu editei a postagem colocando a classe que ele se referencia, mais qual seria a solução pra ele passar os dados.. Não estou entendendo muito...